# How to use Visual Studio Git repository in InteliJ 14

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'v used Visual Studio's Git online repository for my C#.NET projects, and now I want to use it for my InteliJ projects.

I'v created a simple Java "Hello World!" template project, but I can't see where to define my remote git repo (with credentials, of course), so I can pull/push from/to there.

Some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Git needs to create its support files, you do not just configure it in IDEA. You need to either:

1. clone/checkout the project if it already exists in Git via the menu *VCS > Checkout from Version Control > Git*; or
2. Create a Git repository via the menu *VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository*. Then follow the instructions for [Adding a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/). You'll need to do such via the command line. I do not believe IDEA natively supports the `remote` command for git.

Comment: so i guess IDEA doesn't support it in the easy way like visual studio? too bad :(